# my file failed to my destination folder CODE IGNITER

Tags: file, codeigniter, class, upload, continuous-integration

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/con_add_submit_form">

            Product Name: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="product" /><br />
            Add Image: <input  class="form-control" type="file" name="userfile" /><br />
            Description: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" /><br />
            Quantity:<input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity" /><br />
            Price: <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="price" /><br />

           <center> <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="ADD" />&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>shop">CANCEL</a>  </center>
            </form>
```

controller

```
public function con_add_submit_form()
{



             $post = $this->input->post(); // $_POST;
            $userfile  = $this->input->post('userfile'); // $_POST;



            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100000;
            $config['max_width']            = 10000;
            $config['max_height']           = 100000;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($userfile))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());


            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());


            }

    $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');






    $this->data_fetcher->AddUser($post); //calls add user function from data_fetcher model
    redirect(base_url().'shop');
}
```

[Destination FOLDER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VodFz.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read 
[**How to Ask my own questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and find out how to use this site 
[**taking the tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this below using [form validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) and [form helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('shop/con_add_submit_form');?>

Product Name: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="product" /><br />
Add Image: <input  class="form-control" type="file" name="userfile" /><br />
Description: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" /><br />
Quantity:<input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity" /><br />
Price: <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="price" /><br />

<center> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
</center>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

File Uploading Data https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data

controller

Filename: Shop.php

```
<?php

class Shop extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function con_add_submit_form() {

    $data['title'] = 'Welcome to Codeigniter';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product', 'product', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        $this->load->view('your_view', $data);

    } else {

        if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {

            $config['upload_path']  = './assets/uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']  = 100000;
            $config['max_width']  = 10000;
            $config['max_height']  = 100000;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {

                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

                $this->data_fetcher->add_product($this->input->post(), $upload_data);
            }

        } else {

            $this->data_fetcher->add_product($this->input->post());
            redirect(base_url('some_controller'));

        }

    }

    public function add_product($data = array(), $upload_data = array()) {
        $insert_array = array(
            'product' => $data['product'],
            'userfile' => ($upload_data) ? $upload_data['file_name'] : '',
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
            'price' => $data['price'],

        );

        $this->db->insert('yourtablename', $insert_array);
    }

}
```